# Using existing database table for OBIEE login authentication

Tags: authentication, weblogic, obiee

We have a scenario where we have a java web application deployed at a weblogic instance and OBIEE in another. Now, what we want is to authenticate the OBIEE users from using our already existing user base from our webapp database table. I don't have much experience regarding OBIEE or weblogic server administration but by googling a little I have found that OBIEE by default uses the weblogic's embeded LDAP server for authenticating it's users. What we need is a way to configure obiee to use our existing database table users for authentication purpose. How do we achieve this? What are the necessary steps ? Do we need to create a custom  weblogic authentication provider for this ? Any guidance is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Database authentication is possible on OBIEE 11.1.1.5 and higher. I asume that you are good on that side.

Oracle documentation is quite good on this topic, you can check detailed scenario [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/bi.1111/e10543/privileges.htm#BIESC6096)

The basic idea is that you create a SQLAuthenticator that talks between a virtualised identity provider and your database where your users are defined.

It's important to notice that this method works with users/passwords defined in one of your tables and not with database accounts.

Good luck!

Comment: The problem with this standard approach is that we use custom password encryption algorithm, so the standard way described here, will not work for us. Are there any custom way around that you know of we can use ? Do we need to build a custom authentication provider? Thank you.

Comment: When you create SQL Authenticator (following this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/bi.1111/e10543/privileges.htm#BABDGDJA) you have the option of specifying if the password column is on plain text or hashed (default is SHA-1). You can change this default encryption method to any supported by the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) provider configured. If you are using some custom encryption method you might want to play with the JCE providers to add yours.

Comment: I can login using the plain text password enabled but 
Unable to login when using plain text password is disabled. if plain text password is disabled it should use SHA-1 hash by default right ? So, I put SHA-1 hash as password in the database but when trying to login it's not working..

Answer (score 0):

@adn.911,

After setting up your db authentication are you facing the login issue only on analytics or even on weblogic console and em?

If you are able to login to weblogic console but not to analytics, try setting the virtualize property to true and reset the BISystemUser password.